# Ajax to Controller and return file in a IFrame

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am trying to print the contents of an `byte[]` array into an Iframe and then also give the user the option to download the file in pdf format.

In my view I have a button which hooked up to a `ajax` call which passes the `byte[]` to my actionresult which works and the return type is a `FileContentResult`.

However am not sure how to return the File content in my `ajax` response and then set the source of the Iframe to the response I get back from the actionresult?

View

```
<input type="button" value="Show PDF" />
 <div id="DisplayPDF"></div>
```

Jquery / Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on('click', function () {            
        $.ajax({
            url: '/BillPayment/GetPDF',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: '@Model.ROIAgreementApplication' }, //your string data
            success: function (response) {
                $("#DisplayPDF").html(
                    $('<iframe>', {
                        src: this.href,
                        width: '600px',
                        height: "800px"
                    })
                );
            }
        });
    });        
});
```

Actionresult / controller

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult GetPDF(string id)
{
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();

    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id);
    byte[] byteArray = bytes;
    outputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    outputStream.Position = 0;

    return File(outputStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Earlier I was thinking of using `@Url.Action()` in the source attribute of a given Iframe like this

```
<iframe src='@Url.Action("GetPDF","BillPayment", new { id = @Model.ROIAgreementApplication })' width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0" />
```

However it doesn't even get passed to my actionresult?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to read a preexiting PDF file and send the output stream to the browser. Some considerations here:
- you need to set the full HTTP header, since you are missing parameters light length, etc.
- tag application/force-download maybe of your interest, since using application/pdf can cause the file to be opened in the browser using a PDF reader, while the first one will ask the user to download the file.

I think it is not possible to execute any Javascript query inside the src="" field. In deed, I think that there is no need to use any iframe for this purpose. Creating an A object and just calling the URL from the object should do the job. Or even simpler: changing the URL of the current page:

```
window.location.href="path_to_pdf";
```

By the way, this code:

```
 $('input').on('click', function () {
```

makes a reference to a button with the id="input" but does not exists that object in your HTML code. Should be something like:

```
<input type="button" id="input" value="Show PDF" />
```

Here is an example, as requested:

```
CTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').on('click', function () {            
                window.location.href = "http://www.panoramanumismatico.net/articulos/download.php?fid=3324";
            });        
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="input" type="button" value="Show PDF" />

</body>
</html>
```

Do not test it in JSfiddle, since it does not allow to execute external queries.

In the C# side, have a look to this:
https://sourcefirst.wordpress.com/2007/11/20/c-force-file-download/

Comment: Hi Carles can you provide an example please?

Comment: An example of what exactly? By the way, you have an error in the code, since there is no object with ID "input"